# Select From Range of Names

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, filter, sql-server-2008-r2

For example I have this names in the database

```
LastName
Amy
Betty
Camy
Daisy
David
Johnson
```

This works only if want to select From Amy to David:

```
select * from Student
where LastName >= 'A' and LastName <= char(ascii('D') + 1)
order by LastName
```

How I will do it if I only want to select From Amy to Daisy only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm probably missing something that you forgot to include in your question, but) why make life harder than it has to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE LastName BETWEEN 'Amy' AND 'Daisy'
ORDER BY LastName
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31df7/1)

---

To respond to the comment, one way you could do it is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE LastName >= 'Amy'
AND (LastName <= 'Dai' OR LastName LIKE 'Dai%')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1971d/3) demonstrating this should still result in a single index seek.

Comment: What I need is for example the user only type 'Dai'. The daisy should be included

Comment: @KarlxSwanovski Ok I added a second option for you